# Print php table to pdf

Tags: php, css, mysql, pdf

I have a table generated by `PHP` and a lot of MySQL query. It looks like this:

[image]

I need to print this table to a PDF file. I've tried TCPDF and it works great but it doesn't support external CSS. I've tried to JSON the item in my table to send them with POST to the page but it doesn't work.
So, the question is, there's any simple (I really hope for it) to send via a button all the table and print it into PDF?

Comment: TCPDF works better.Try to use only allowed css in TCPDF.Please refer below link  for supported css in TCPDF.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37461529/print-php-table-to-pdf

Comment: `Ctrl+P` for Windows. `Command+P` for Mac.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a "nice looking" conversion, you can use [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org). It uses `Webkit` engine to generate PDF from an HTML source. It is distributed both, as source code and as binary images for common OS.

If you can execute binaries in your host, I'd give it a try.

Comment: I can't install programs on the host because I'm using a web hosting service.